Preventing Sign out from Microsoft edge
Is there a script or registry edit that can prevent my family computer users from signing out of my Microsoft account in edge? I already searched for extensions for that problem but couldn't find any solution

Have you considered using different (Windows) user profiles? There are no extensions that can prevent a user, from specifically, switching which Edge profile will be used.
